# Is there a way to use environment variable in another directory in a node.js app

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, undefined

I have a project with folder structure is as follows,

Root > client, server

I want to use the environment variables form the .env file of my Root directory in the /Server/src, But when I try to import it in /Server/src the environment variables are undefined.

Is there a way to use those environment variables in the Server directory?

```
// from Root directory
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
}
```

```
// from Server directory
const { NODE_ENV,} = require("./config");

console.log(NODE_ENV); //value returns undefined
```

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

You can specify a custom path in your client folder files to the .env file by going

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' })
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

I see what you're trying to do, but unless the file path is `"./config"` then it won't work.  You said it is in the root directory, so likely you are not using the right path.  There will need to be at least one `../` to get back out of the server directory and into the root directory to access the file you're exporting from.

That being said, why bother?  You should just require dotenv in any file you need to access the environment variables.  I don't know what you're saving by using this method.

Pretty much the same amount of code, but less, since you're not creating this extra layer of abstraction:

```
// from Server directory
require("dotenv").config();

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

Comment: well you see I have a complex folder structure going on there so, When I deploy it to the cloud I only get to set environment variables in the root directory, But I need those in the server directory to work with the application. If I can't get this to work I might have to restructure the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

If it is from root directory you can use `./` I tried this and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).